# Different intellisense for different array declarations

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I am declaring an integer array in following two ways:

```
Array numbers = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), 10);
int[] numbers1 = new int[6];
```

I presumed that the variables `numbers` and `numbers1` both are similar. But the intellisense I get for these two are different. I get more options for `numbers1`.

Why is it so?

Comment: Casting to `Array` loses a lot of type information, so why are you surprised that you see less in intellisense? Just like you see even less when you cast to `object`. In particular LINQ will only apply to the second, since `Array` doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: @CodesInChaos, I did not know that the two declarations are different. That is why I was surprised to see this difference. And upon seeing this difference, I realized that there is some difference in these two. Rawling has done an excellend job of clarifying it for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that `numbers1` implements `IEnumerable<int>` as well as `IEnumerable`; `numbers` only implements `IEnumerable`.

(Basically, `numbers`  knows it is a sequence, but not what *type* of sequence it is; `numbers1` knows it is a sequence *of `int`s*.)

Since I have the line `using System.Linq` at the start of my program, I get a *lot* of LINQ extension methods to use on `numbers1`, but only a few on `numbers`.

(LINQ defines methods for querying arrays and other sequences. Since you can only make *interesting* queries on sequences when you know *what type of object is in the sequence*, a lot of the methods are only avaiable for `IEnumerable<something>` sequences, not plain `IEnumerable` sequences.)

If I take out `using System.Linq`, I get the exact same options on the two of them.

It could be that you *yourself* have defined a lot of extension methods for `IEnumerable<int>`, but it's probably LINQ.

Comment: This answers my question! Many thanks, Rawling. Marking this as the answer!